# context.withtimeout without calling cancel

Tags: go

I want to run something like the following:

```
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
mongoClient, err = mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(connectionUrl))
return mongoClient, err
```

The reason for this is that I want the client to timeout quicker when I'm running tests, so I am trying to use context.WithTimeout with a configurable timeout. The code above sits in a function that returns a singleton mongo *Client. I also want to be able to maintain a live connection without having to call Connect() everytime I call a function which executes mongodb operations to keep certain critical responses as quick as possible.

In order to meet these requirements, I want to run the above code without deferring the cancel() because I want to keep the connection alive throughout the lifetime of my program. However, I am getting the warning:

> the cancel function returned by context.WithTimeout should be called,
> not discarded, to avoid a context leak

Should I be listening to the warning here, or should I be ignoring it? Search results seem to say that it's not a good idea to ignore the warning, but calling cancel seems to be bad here. What's so bad about leaking context if I want it to remain in memory in the first place?

Bonus question: Is there an easy way in Go to suppress a particular warning with something like an annotation?

Comment: Canceling the context after the Connect function returns has no impact on the client. You should fix the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* listen to the documentation. Not canceling the context will leak a goroutine. The leak will not be permanent however since you are probably using a short timeout (e.g. 30s - the context will be cancelled anyway). But it's just good practice to follow the documentation (*)

As for your concern with the created connection's lifespan - this is not an issue. The context is used *during* DB connection creation, but once established, any future calls on that connection will work (even if the connect context is cancelled after the fact).

---

(*) there are real life cases where creating a timeout may seem innocuous as they are ephemeral. However if your API's request rate is sufficient high - the backlog of goroutines waiting for these contexts to naturally expire can case resource constraints. Proactively cancelling (and this freeing up) resources you no longer need, help to alleviate such constraints.